# On a transmission line, can I divide the voltage in phasor form across a load by the impedance of the load to get a current?

Tags: electromagnetism

Would this be correct? I'm doing that but also doing a method given in my textbook, but I am getting the same answer. Can someone confirm?

Also, this won't work when it's a short-circuit right?

Comment: sounds like an electrical engineering question.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson No, it's only a sophomore-level undergrad question.

Comment: in electrical engineering, right?  you're not doing transmission lines (or "distributed networks") with the telegrapher's equations and the like outside an EE class, are you?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Well then you can call it basic EE

Comment: i dunno, solving telegrapher's equations is pretty tough EE.  i think at least junior level.  sophomore level is when you're just beginning to learn circuits and impedances and phasors and the like.  applying the concepts to transmission lines is harder.

Comment: I definitely think this is on topic here.